# mapfragment from google maps api on android is blank

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

i have obtained an api key from code.google.com and put it in my manifest file.
i instantiated a mapfragment in my res.layout and it loads only a blank screen with the + and - zoom buttons overlayed.
here is my manifest

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true"/>
    <permission
          android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my api key"/>
    </application>

</manifest>

and my layout.xml
    <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you've activated the Google Maps Android API v2 and not the Google Maps API v2 at your API console? It was a problem that I ran in to.

Comment: i just checked and saw that i had only google maps API v2 enabled.  i clicked enable under the services tab to enable google maps android api v2.  is there some waiting period before this will fix it? is there anything else i need to configure for google maps android api v2?

Comment: No waiting period. Just enable Google Maps Android API v2 and get your API key.

Comment: hmmm at first when i attempted that switch it did not work.  then i switched my API key from the intuitive "Key for Android apps (with certificates)" to "Key for browser apps (with referers)"
and it now works.  I don't know what the difference is or if i am going to run into future problems.  perhaps my app doesnt have a certificate?? does eclipse do this automatically?

Comment: It needs to be set up properly. I use Key for Android apps (with certificates). It should have a list of android apps that it's activated for (only one app in my case). If not then you've missed a step. Try this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_key

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've set up `Google Maps Android API v2` and not `Google Maps API v2` in your API console.

This is a good guide to follow for more information:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_key

Comment: I think they are the same, but not!

Comment: +1 freaking one, I had the regular API enabled XD.. Thank you

Comment: I like to necro year old posts